# How to clear variables in ipython?

Tags: python, memory, ipython

Sometimes I rerun a script within the same ipython session and I get bad surprises when variables haven't been cleared. How do I clear all variables?
And is it possible to force this somehow every time I invoke the magic command `%run`?

Answer (score 264, accepted):

`%reset` seems to clear defined variables.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to set it automatically before each %run?

Comment: Don't know, but you could run python script from shell terminal.

Comment: hey grasshopper did you find out how to do this? So annoying!

Comment: You could convert your script into a function to keep the global namespace clean.

Comment: Just found %reset -f clears the global namespace without user confirmation

Comment: yes reset -f is great, no need to manually confirm every time any more :)

Comment: @aisbaa what is the "%" sign called in this case ?

Comment: @Victor `%` is used for ipython magic commands here's `%reset` https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset

Comment: With %reset, I got errors like 
ERROR: root: Invalid alias: The name clear can't be aliased because it is another magic command.
I assume I can ignore these types of errors.

Answer (score 71):

EDITED after @ErdemKAYA comment.

To erase a variable, use the magic command:

```
%reset_selective <regular_expression>
```

The variables that are erased from the namespace are the one matching the given `<regular_expression>`.

Therefore

```
%reset_selective -f a
```

will erase **all** the variables containing an `a`.

Instead, to erase only `a` and not `aa`:

```
In: a, aa = 1, 2
In: %reset_selective -f "^a$"
In: a  # raise NameError
In: aa  # returns 2
```

see as well `%reset_selective?` for more examples and [https://regexone.com/](https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs) for a regex tutorial.

To erase all the variables in the namespace see:

```
%reset?
```

Comment: Otherwise "del a" from python, can be used as well.

Answer (score 67):

In iPython you can remove a **single** variable like this:

```
del x
```

Answer (score 24):

I tried

```
%reset -f
```

and cleared all the variables and contents without prompt. `-f` does the force action on the given command without prompting for *yes/no*.

Wish this helps.. :)

Answer (score 17):

Adding the following lines to a new script will clear all variables each time you rerun the script:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
```

To make life easy, you can add them to your default template.

In Spyder: `Tools>Preferences>Editor>Edit template`

Comment: I like this as it can also be run from a script.

Answer (score 16):

Apart from the methods mentioned earlier. You can also use the command del to remove multiple variables

```
del variable1,variable2
```

Answer (score 5):

The `get_ipython().magic()` method raises a DeprecationWarning in ipython 8.1. Here is the new version of [Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7862338/carl)'s answer

```
 from IPython import get_ipython
 get_ipython().run_line_magic('reset', '-sf')
```

Add these lines to a file you are editing. Then at the ipython command prompt you can type,

```
%run file_you_are_editing.py
```

Comment: This answer works for people using for loops, multi files and doesn't want to get their modules erased with the  `%reset` command

Answer (score 0):

An quit option in the Console Panel will also clear all variables in variable explorer

*** Note that you will be loosing all the code which you have run in Console Panel