# Strange module reload behavior in spyder or IPython

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I have an issue re-running a script in spyder, which dynamically tabulates some of its own attributes.

Here is a minimal example that is representative of what I am doing. I have a source script that I run with the normal Run (F5) command. It runs in the same directory that it lives in:

```
runfile('C:/some/path/test.py', wdir='C:/some/path')
```

**test.py**

```
import sys

def x():
    pass

def y():
    pass

x.add = y.add = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [obj for obj in tuple(sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.values())
                if getattr(obj, 'add', False)]
    print(a)
```

I can re-run this script a couple of times, and always get the same expected result:

```
[<function x at 0x0000025E793DBD90>, <function y at 0x0000025E793DB598>]
```

I would expect that if I change the name of one of the functions, say from `x` to `f`, and the attribute assignment to `f.add = y.add = True`, I would get the same result, but with `x` changed to `f`. Instead, I get

```
[<function x at 0x0000025E793DB510>, <function y at 0x0000025E793DBBF8>, <function f at 0x0000025E793DBA60>]
```

Given that the new function `f` shows up in the list, but the old `x` is still there as well, I think that the module cache for the script is not being cleared properly.

I have been manually clearing the workspace using the eraser button over the console, but I feel like there must be a better solution, or at least an explanation of what is happening. Perhaps it is an issue with UMR?

I am running Spyder 3.3.3 with the following: Python 3.7.3 64-bit | Qt 5.9.6 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Windows 10, IPython 7.4.9

Comment: Along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738537/builtin-function-not-working-with-spyder/47738834#47738834) I expect

Comment: Spyder caches variables and results without clearing them. That is not on accident. There is a way around it: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48038888/10366273)

Comment: It has some cool uses. You can run a function that takes 10 mins to process data and return it to a global name, then just hash that function call out for every subsequent run and never have to incur the processing time again (until you wipe the namespace, that is). Until you learn that that name is just gonna hang around indefinitely, though, it's more likely that you will be bitten by it

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb. I would accept an answer with a combination of that and roganjosh's comment/GitHub thread

Comment: @roganjosh. Makes sense. That's pretty much the explanation I was looking for. I didn't realize that the contaimination was two-way, which actually is pretty helpful. The option to clear vars before running is helpful

Comment: My answer I linked to does point to the same solution as Caleb gave, but since I'm not too fussed about fleshing this out into an answer and you already invited them to give an answer, I will give them chance to put one together before I answer :)

Comment: One thing I will look into, though, is whether it still applies for V4 because I have the Beta installed here and I think they may have changed the default behaviour

Comment: @roganjosh. I think part of the issue is that I was expecting an intermediate option: not clearing the console variables, but completely reloading the module I care about

Comment: A totally reasonable expectation. I'm _not sure_ whether the way they configured the global namespace allows it to flow one way even going forward, but it's totally what I expected to happen. I'll have a play. Separately, it looks like the "clear namespace on each script" is still off by default in V4 Beta

Comment: I added it to the bottom but you can do `reset_selective` to clear specific ones matching regex

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb. Yep, that's a pretty helpful option to. I think I'll just switch to `%run` line magic for now, since it does what I expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature in Spyder that is built on purpose to allow you to continue running from stop points, especially when considering longer run times to generate specific results, and also powers the [variable explorer](https://docs.spyder-ide.org/variableexplorer.html) function.

There is a way around it though following the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48038888/10366273) to *Clear all variables before each run* or by restarting.

However, as pointed out by [roganjosh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799172/roganjosh), clearing the namespace is not necessarily better.

> You can run a function that takes 10 mins to process data and return it to a global name, then just hash that function call out for every subsequent run and never have to incur the processing time again (until you wipe the namespace, that is).

If you want to only reset one or a group of variables, you can use [reset_selective](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-reset_selective)

```
%reset_selective [-f] regex
```

Comment: @roganjosh no problem!