# Reset iPython %run file.py without restarting

Tags: ipython

I wrote up the [example code for Python logging module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50302365/logging-module-sample-code-repeats-messages-n-times-each-call) and discovered odd behavior. The logging messages duplicated each time I executed: `%run main.py`. At first the only way to clear the duplication was to exit iPython (CTRL-D). User unutbu posted an explantion and solution. Ok. Solved.

But as a matter of development and practice using iPython, Can I reset iPython (in a way that would remove these instances of the logger handler object) without restarting iPython?

This question has been asked before, but evidently they didn't have [this test code](https://ptpb.pw/Sk_j) to contend with.

[Reset ipython kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603456/reset-ipython-kernel)

[How to clear variables in ipython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934204/how-to-clear-variables-in-ipython)

The simple option was uneffective:

```
In [29]: %reset
Once deleted, variables cannot be recovered. Proceed (y/[n])? y

In [30]: %run main2
2018-05-12 1335:00 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-12 1335:00 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-12 1335:00 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-12 1335:00 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
2018-05-12 1335:00 - WARNING - 3. This is a warning!
```

After restart, you will only see one of these lines, and not one for each previous execution of the `%run` magic.

Another suggestion didn't work as expected (maybe something changed since 2016?):

```
In [28]: import IPython
    ...: app = IPython.Application.instance()
    ...: app.kernel.do_shutdown(True)  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-59afc6e6c255> in <module>()
      1 import IPython
      2 app = IPython.Application.instance()
----> 3 app.kernel.do_shutdown(True)
AttributeError: 'TerminalIPythonApp' object has no attribute 'kernel'
```

I'm running Arch with i3, and another suggestion of CTRL-. doesn't work.